# How to create non-hierarchical navigation in iPad App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have an iPad App with three main screens, each with his own ViewController.
On these screens are buttons to navigate to the other screens.

The navigation between these screens is not hierarchical. It must be possible to navigate from screen 1 to 3, then to 2, to 1 and so on. So, I don't want to push and pop, but just show the next ViewController.

I don't know how to build such a structure. It looks a little like a tabbed application, but is there another way to implement this? I use storyboards, by the way. Also animations when changing from one page to another is not necessary.

Comment: You can create a custom container view controller that allows navigation among its children whatever way you define.  How do you want the user to move among them?

Comment: Every screen has two buttons to navigate to the other screen. Screen 1 has buttons to go to 2 and 3, Screen 2 has buttons to go to 1 and 3, Screen 3 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to have the 'slide' animation of the hierarchical UINavigationController, there are a few options.

You could implement this using the popToViewController method in the UINavigationController. To get the animations going in the correct direction, you can use custom transitions.

```
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Another thing you could do, depending on how much of this navigation you need to save, and whether you need to have state on return, is to just push new instances of the viewControllers onto the UINavigationController and relying on it to manage the memory of the stack well.

If you can live without these transitions, you are correct in assuming that a UITabBarController is a better way to go.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Animations are not necessary (unwanted, even). Then, a UITabBarController is the way to go?

Comment: I have been working on the UITabBarController solution as you proposed. I have embedded the three ViewControllers in a TabBarController. When I want to switch from one page to the other I need to access the self.tabBarController property of the ViewController. That property is nil. I think that has to do with the fact that I don't show the Tab Bar and Tab Items.
Any thoughts on this? I don't want to show a Tab Bar.

Comment: A way that you could do this is to hide the tab bar by either putting it off screen, or covering it. In this case, you would have to send a command to the tabBarController in order to switch between the views.
To do this, just use 
[controller setSelectedIndex:index];
Where controller is the UITabBarController, and index is the index of the view controller you are trying to present

Comment: I still have problems to implement the complete structure. In the StoryBoard I have embedded the three ViewControllers in the TabBarController. However, the tabBarController property of the ViewControllers remain nil and also the parentViewController property remains nil, while both should contain a reference to the TabBarController. I am comparing my App to the template Tabbed App in Xcode and I don't see any differences. I still am missing something, but what??

Comment: Hmm.. kind of out of ideas without seeing the code. My suggestion now would be to open a new project from the Xcode UITabBarController template, and start copying your functionality into that. Do it slowly, and you'll probably see where it breaks. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: Finally found what caused the confusion. In the file inspector, the Target Membership panel, the right target wasn't selected.
Now, everything works fine and the tabbed behavior works as requested.
Thanks!